# How to implement recv and send at one time correctly

Tags: python, websocket, chat, send, recv

I am trying to messing up with Websockets module and after checking the main page:
https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html

I did following:

**SERVER**

```
# SERVER

import  asyncio
import websockets
import nest_asyncio

USERS = {}

async def set_online(websocket, user_name):
    USERS[user_name] = websocket
    await notify()
    
async def set_offline(websocket, user_name):
    USERS.pop(user_name, None)
    await notify()


async def notify():
    if USERS:
        message = "Online users: {}\n".format(len(USERS))
        print (message)
        #await asyncio.wait([user.send(message) for user in USERS])
    else:
        message = "Online users: 0\n"
        print (message)
        
        
async def server(websocket, path):
    user_name = await websocket.recv()
    await set_online(websocket, user_name)
        
    try:
        async for message in websocket:
            for user_name, user_ws in USERS.items():
                if websocket == user_ws:
                    print (f"{user_name}: {message}")
            
    finally:
        await set_offline(websocket, user_name)
        


start_server = websockets.serve(server, "localhost", 3000, 
                                        ping_interval=None)

nest_asyncio.apply()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(start_server)
loop.run_forever()
```

and also:

**CLIENT**

```
# CLIENT

import asyncio
import websockets
import nest_asyncio


async def client(localhost, port):
    uri = "ws://{0}:{1}".format(localhost, str(port))
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        user_name = input("set your name: ")
        await websocket.send(f"{user_name}")
        
        while True:
            message = input("> ")

            if message == "/quit":
                break
            else:
                await websocket.send(message)

host = "localhost"
port = 3000

nest_asyncio.apply()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(client(host, port))
```

so all works as expected but I would like to achieve that each user can receive the answer as well from other users.
I found there is a conflict when I want to use `websocket.send(message)` in for loop `async for message in websocket:` on SERVER side

The link which I paste above, I think has a solution but I am struggling to figure out how to use it properly in my script.
I believe I need to create two tasks (send and recv) which will work in parallel.

Like:

```
async def handler(websocket, path):
    consumer_task = asyncio.ensure_future(consumer_handler(websocket, path))
    producer_task = asyncio.ensure_future(producer_handler(websocket, path))
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait([consumer_task, producer_task],return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
    for task in pending:
        task.cancel()
```

the following is displayed on the website which I provided above, just one thing needs to be changed from `asyncio.ensure_future` to `asyncio.create_task`. I implemented function `handler`, `producer`, `consumer`, `producer_handler` and `consumer_handler` to make it works but no luck.

Could someone provide an example or how this should be set up correctly?
I believe `asyncio.create_task` should be used on both (SERVER and CLIENT) so they both receive and send at one time.

This is pretty long but I hope someone can help me with it and also maybe my part of script will be handy for someone as well!